# Save and retrieve the value of the variables

Tags: excel, vba, dll

I am programming a macro in Excel-VBA to perform different calculations by phases within a project.

I need to schedule a way to save the work I have calculated in one form at a time, so I can continue another day.

Is there any way to write all the values of variables that have already been assigned or calculated, in a file (.txt, .dat ...)?

So that the value of the stored variables can be recovered later, and continue working.

It would work as the "save", "save as", "open" buttons. But with the variables entered or calculated in my form.

How can all the variables that already have value be saved?

If I program them to be saved one by one, I get an error as expected, when I try to save a variable that I have not yet calculated ...

Thank you very much for the help!!

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can't do what you want. Variables are in memory only during execution of code. To *save* the values, you need to store the value somewhere, i.e, a spreadsheet, a database or something. You have no posted anything about your project, so I will answer that you can save the value in a cell, save the workbook, and continue your project tomorrow

Comment: Your question is too broad... There's a lot of different ways to do what you're asking for. Some of those are simple and others are more complicated. It depends of the nature of your goal. For example, why don't use the excel file itself to store your data?

Comment: Hello, sorry for not having had better what I was asking.

I am preparing a form, in which some input data is requested from the user, and the code of the form, is making calculations and is sequentially obtaining components for a machine.
The process is long, and I am looking for that if the user does not complete it once, I can leave it, and continue later.
Or in case you want to recover the results already calculated once, just have to "load" them, do not re-enter all the data and calculate everything.

Comment: I've been trying to do that, with a "save" button, which saves all the values I've entered and calculated so far in an external file (for example .txt or .dat) and with an "open" button that allows loading all the data saved in that file and continue working.

I can not save this data in Excel cells, because the program is expected to be used to perform many different calculations.

Comment: Why can't you store them in a sheet in the file which is hidden, or very hidden?

Comment: Because I'm looking for a way to do it that involves not modifying the excel document.

On the one hand there is the Excel with the calculation program, and on the other hand there are the saved files, one for each calculation made that can be opened and revised if necessary.

Comment: If you don't want to store it in Excel, you could store them also somehow in a text file. But there is no out of the box way to do so, you have to program it.

Answer (score 1):

I can show you how to save data on an external file. Let's imagine you want to save four values (for four variables) on the file `C:\DATA.dat`. The four variables are `DAT1`, `DAT2`, `DAT3` and `DAT4` (a Boolean, an Integer, a Single and a String). You could use the next code (on a VBA module of your workbook) to do that:

```
Sub SaveDATA()

    'Variables:
        Dim FilePath As String: FilePath = "C:\DATA.dat"
        Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject: Dim Writer As TextStream

        Dim DAT1 As Boolean: DAT1 = False
        Dim DAT2 As Integer: DAT2 = 3
        Dim DAT3 As Single: DAT3 = 3 / 7
        Dim DAT4 As String: DAT4 = "Another example"

    'Create/Overwrite the file:
        Set Writer = FSO.CreateTextFile(FilePath, True)

    'Write the file:
        Writer.WriteLine (DAT1)
        Writer.WriteLine (DAT2)
        Writer.WriteLine (DAT3)
        Writer.WriteLine (DAT4)

    'Close the file:
        Writer.Close

End Sub
```

To retrieve the data you saved on the file you have to use something similar to the next code:

```
Sub ReadDATA()

    'Variables:
        Dim FilePath As String: FilePath = "C:\DATA.dat"
        Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject: Dim Reader As TextStream

        Dim DAT1 As Boolean
        Dim DAT2 As Integer
        Dim DAT3 As Single
        Dim DAT4 As String

    'Open the file:
        Set Reader = FSO.OpenTextFile(FilePath)

    'Read the file:
        DAT1 = Reader.ReadLine
        DAT2 = Val(Reader.ReadLine)
        DAT3 = Val(Reader.ReadLine)
        DAT4 = Reader.ReadLine

    'Close the file:
        Reader.Close

End Sub
```

For both macros to work, you have to import `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` reference (just go to `Tools -> References` and check it.

I won't do the rest of the work for you (for now)! That's up to you... Make some experiences! That's the best way to learn!

Comment: Thank you very much for the help !!!!, I will try with this code, to see if I can get it to work and review the references.